# Excel VBA Logical operator Not wildcard*

Tags: vba, excel

I'm struggling with the Excel Operators I have spent quite some time searching I feel as if I am close I'm trying to code this If statement if the value does not begin with 722* and does not equal PI then execute code immediately below else execute code under the else statement.

```
If Not CStr(Cells(r, cC)) = "722*" And Not CStr(Cells(r, cS)) = "PI" Then
```

Comment: Use `left`. `If Not left(CStr(Cells(r, cC),3) = "722"`

Comment: the * way is more versatile and is helpful for future learning

Comment: Versatility is not always good,  wildcards are much heavier to compute than `Left` If you don't need a Lamborgini then don't use it.

Comment: Your requirement states `does not begin` so `left` is the right tool. Part of learning is to know which tool to use ~_^ If wildcards is needed, perhaps consider `instr`.

Comment: following @findwindow suggestion and your _versatility_ need you may want to use `If Not (Left(CStr(Cells(r, cC)),3) = "722" and Len(Cells(r, cC))>3)`. but really wouldn't say why...

Comment: I think @litelite took a lambo to work today^^

Comment: @user3598756 a string that is only "722" does begin with "722" your solution ignores that

Comment: @litelite I assumed that "*" would stand for _"there is to be something more"_.. Should it stand for _"may be there is something more"_ then just change 3 with 2. but then it'd loose any meaning...

Comment: @user3598756 yes it is _may_ as in might not be there. And you still don't need the `>2` because the `=722` will do it (if it's smaller than two how vould it ever be equal to 722)

Comment: @litelite that's precisely what I meant with _"but then it'd loose any meaning..."_ so that either be done with `Left` only or with `Left` _and_ `Len(..)>3`

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be to use `Left`

```
If Not Left(CStr(Cells(r, cC),3) = "722"
```

If you want to use wildcards, use `Like`:

```
If Not Cells(r, cC)) Like "722*" Then
```

Comparing them with `=` treats `*` simply as a character.

Edit2: apparently I was wrong about the computational effort of Like. Like seems to be the faster method (in this case), especially if there is no match (lazy evaluation I guess). Obviously the total cpu and memory usage is so small in both cases that it's up to your preference which one to choose.

This is what I found:
`s Like "722*"` is faster than `Left(s,3) = "722"`

`s Like "*722"` is slower than `Right(s,3) = "722"`

`s Like "*722*"` is slower than `Instr(1,s,"722")>0`

The magnitude of the difference varies depending on string length and if there is a match or not (e.g. `s Like "722*"` is very fast if `s` doesn't start with `7` and `Left` and `Right` don't suffer as much as `Like` if you replace "722" with something longer)

Comment: I just want to point out that the `like` operator will be much heavier to compute than a simple `=` and a `left`.

Comment: @litelite yup, added it.

Comment: @litelite, where did you get the idea that the `like` operator is much heavier to compute than a left? Do you have some facts to support that?

Comment: @FlorentB. I originally didn't include it in my post because I never did the research but believed the others that posted here. I would think that Left is probably the most efficient because copying the first n characters of a string should be pretty quick. The question is if Like has overhead because it prepares for a more complex task?

Comment: @FlorentB. I just tried it and the Like method was 4 times as fast as Left. Maybe allocating new a string and then comparing it vs just comparing it makes the difference?

Comment: @arcadeprecinct, like you mentioned, the difference is so low, that recommending one solution over another for performance reason would be ridiculous. My guess is that the low complexity of the pattern beats the memory allocation/management for the new string.